# Access html text through python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get text (marked by hashtags).

```
<div class="XYZ">
        <h5>
    "
          #######Reports due by##############
    "
          <span class="hbl" data-hint="task due date">
            <i class="icon-boxy-sign"></i>
          </span>
        </h5>
        <script type="jsv#61^"></script><script type="jsv#123_"></script>
        <script type="jsv#60^"></script><script type="jsv#124_"></script>
      <script type="jsv#59^"></script><p>#################07/10/2020#######################</p><script type="jsv/125^"></script>
    <script type="jsv/52_"></script><script type="jsv/24^"></script>
        <script type="jsv/42_"></script><script type="jsv/23^"></script>
      </div>
```

Python line to get the text inside the hashtags:

```
txt = dat =wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="XYZ"]'))).text
```

I expect the line to print: "Reports due by" and "07/10/2020, I keep getting timeoutException and Unable to locate element errors.

Comment: HTML code pls, atleast some. We can't help u without it.

Comment: Edited just a few seconds before you asked :)

Comment: Try `div.XYZ` instead of `div[class="XYZ"]` (see [class selector docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp))

Comment: div.XYZ not working either. And I don't think that python syntax!

Comment: is the element inside frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were close. To extract the text (marked by hashtags) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.XYZ"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='XYZ']"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)

Comment: I have the correct imports. Neither expression above works for this particular situation. CSS_SELECTOR returns NONE Type, and XPATH times out! Is there a way to access the strings by their tags? <h5> and <p>. I think that's the only hope left.

Comment: I also have the correct wait "from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait" thanks

Comment: Marking this solution because it shows good response effort, and will help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change By. CSS_SELECTOR to By.XPATH and update locator to '//div[@class='XYZ']'. Should work.

Comment: Tried:  (By.XPATH, '//div[@class='XYZ']). No Luck!